# How to put your App on facebook for Approval to get Friendlist

Tags: ios, facebook

I am developing an application and in that I have an option "Invite From Facebook". What I have to do is to fetch the names of the friends and send them invite for my application. What I have seen so fat then in latest Facebook API we can fetch these things directly. Someone told me to you have to submit the App for the approval first and after that we can have the friend list from the Facebook. **So I just want to know the steps how can I submit my App to facebook inorder to get the friendlist**. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

The process for submission app is not easy. We need to strictly follow the guidelines. We need to sure what type of App we are developing and list of permissions are needed. Due to spamming by many Facebook App developers, Facebook app center required exact reason to get approve the required permission.

To submit an iOS App for Review before you release your app on store, you will need to submit the development binary version(an IPA/build, created using apple development certificate) through the submission form. (Read following tutorials for more detials)

For more details: 

[App Development - Facebook for Developers App Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review)

[App Center Guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/guidelines%60) 

[Submission process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process)

Please go through the submission guidelines as well.